# How to get value from CLOB column using xml tag and tag id Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

I have :

```
<Home>
    <Member id="1">
        <Name>John</Name>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
    </Member>
    <Member id="2">
        <Name>Peter</Name>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
    </Member>
</Home>
```

and I want to get "John"

This not get anything :

```
select  xmltype(clob_column).extract('//Home/Member[id=1]/Name/text()').getStringVal() from MY_TABLE;
```

This get "JohnPeter" :

```
select  xmltype(clob_column).extract('//Home/Member/Name/text()').getStringVal() from MY_TABLE;
```

******but I want to get just "John"**

Comment: For your understanding, the first XPath expression returns nothing because the condition `[id=1]` looks for a child element named `id` with value `1`, whereas you want to check for an attribute named `id` with value `1`.  To check for an attribute `id` with value `1`, use the condition `[@id=1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `EXTRACT` is deprecated for XML functions, you will probably want to use a supported function such as  `XMLTABLE`, `XMLCAST`, or `XMLQUERY`. I find `XMLTABLE` the easiest to work with and the example below can be used to get the ID, Name, and Gender in a table structure which you can then add a normal `WHERE` clause to filter the data as you see fit.

```sql
WITH mytable (xmlclob) AS (SELECT EMPTY_CLOB () || '<Home>
    <Member id="1">
        <Name>John</Name>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
    </Member>
    <Member id="2">
        <Name>Peter</Name>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
    </Member>
</Home>' FROM DUAL)
SELECT x.*
  FROM mytable  m
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE ('/Home/Member'
                 PASSING xmltype (m.xmlclob)
                 COLUMNS member_id path '@id', name PATH 'Name', gender PATH 'Gender') x;


   MEMBER_ID     NAME    GENDER
____________ ________ _________
1            John     Male
2            Peter    Male
```